# Array keeps resetting to zero

Tags: c#, arrays, class

i've created a method that uses a property and then inserts that property into an array. this property is from another class "player" and I am trying to get the array to store the totals for each player, however when it increments to the next player it resets the other players to zero.

```
private void GetGrandTotal()
{
    int[] grandTotals = new int[players.Count];
    grandTotals[currentPlayerIndex] = currentPlayer.GrandTotal;
}
```

CurrentPlayerIndex is a variable that holds the current players index in a binding list.

Comment: Declare array outside this method as a global so it will not re initialize this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are re initializing array each time you call the method, so declare and initialize the array globally **ONCE** and in the method, just add elements to the array

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
private void GetGrandTotal()
{
    int[] grandTotals = new int[players.Count];
    grandTotals[currentPlayerIndex] = currentPlayer.GrandTotal;
}
```

grandTotals will have a size with players Count and set the Current Player's GrandTotal. Thats OK. But if you call this again you will lost grandTotals because you will get a new **instance** of it and it will resize and set new player's grandTotal. That should be like this;

```
    int[] grandTotals = new int[players.Count];
    private void GetGrandTotal()
    {
        grandTotals[currentPlayerIndex] = currentPlayer.GrandTotal;
    }
```

So the array won't have a new instance everytime function called. But carefull about the instance of the class of this function belongs. If the class have a new instance you will face this problem again.

Hope helps.